# SQL two criteria from one group-by

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.0

I have a table with some "functionally duplicate" records - different IDs, but the 4 columns of "user data" (of even more columns) are identical. I've got a query working that will select all records that have such duplicates.

Now I want to select, from each group of duplicates, first any of them that have column `A` not null - and I've verified from the data that there are at most 1 such rows per group - and if there are none in this particular group, then the minimum of column `ID`.

How do I select that? I can't exactly use a non-aggregate in the THEN of a CASE and an aggregate in the ELSE. E.g. this doesn't work:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN d.A IS NULL THEN d.ID
           ELSE MIN(d.ID) END,
       d.B,
       d.C,
       d.E,
       d.F
FROM TABLE T
JOIN (my duplicate query here) D ON T.B=D.B
AND T.C=D.C
AND T.E=D.E
AND T.F=D.F
GROUP BY T.B,
         T.C,
         T.E,
         T.F
```

Error being:

> column A must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: Perhaps `COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN d.A IS NOT NULL THEN d.ID ELSE NULL END), MIN(D.ID))`? It considers D.ID only if D.A is not null; if none can be found, min(d.id) will be returned.

Comment: Perfect!  Post as an answer and I will accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be **radically simpler**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b, c, e, f)
       b, c, e, f, id   -- add more columns freely
FROM   (<duplicate query here>) sub
ORDER  BY b, c, e, f, (a IS NOT NULL), id
```

- Your duplicate query has all columns. No need to `JOIN` to the base table again.
- Use the Postgres extension of the standard SQL `DISTINCT`: [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

  - [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- Postgres has a proper boolean type. You can `ORDER BY` boolean expression directly. The sequence is `FALSE` (0), `TRUE` (1), `NULL` (NULL). If a is NULL, this expression is `FALSE` and sorts first: `(a IS NOT NULL)`. The rest is ordered by `id`. Voilá.
- Selection of `ID` happens automatically. According to your description you want the ID of the row selected in this query. Nothing more to do.
- You can probably integrate this into your duplicate query directly.